# If/else statement goes straight to else

Tags: javascript, node.js

My if/else statement goes straight to else and I cant seem to figure out why. Here is my code:

```
var sentiment = require ('sentiment');
var twitterSentiment;
var geoColor;
var results; 
var twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: credentials.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: credentials.consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: credentials.access_token_key,
    access_token_secret: credentials.access_token_secret
});

twit.stream(
    'statuses/filter',
    { 'locations': location },
    function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            console.log(tweet.text);
            results = sentiment (tweet.text);  
            twitterSentiment = results;


            //Comparison of Sentiment Scores 
              if (twitterSentiment == 0) {
                geoColor = '#B5B5B5';
               } 

            else if (twitterSentiment < 0) {
                geoColor = '#FC0828';
            } 
            else {
                geoColor = '#00DE1E';
            }

             console.log (geoColor);         
        });
    });
```

This is an example output:

```
 omg yes!!
#00DE1E
Do you think will actually understand? I want to ask mine the same question. Just not sure I'm ready to have that conversation.
#00DE1E
 A thing of beauty by:
 @youtube
#00DE1E
do you still do this??
#00DE1E
```

As you can see all the tweets are being identified by only one color; almost as if my `if/else` statement is not implemented correctly?

When I change `console.log (geoColor);` to `console.log (results);` This is my output:

```
   omg yes!!
{ score: 1,
  comparative: 0.25,
  tokens: [ 'omg', 'yes' ],
  words: [ 'yes' ],
  positive: [ 'yes' ],
  negative: [] }

 Do you think will actually understand? I want to ask mine the same question. Just not sure I'm ready to have that conversation.
{ score: 1,
  comparative: 0.041666666666666664,
  tokens: 
   [ 
     'do',
     'you',
     'think',
     'will',
     'actually',
     'understand',
     'i',
     'want',
     'to',
     'ask',
     'mine',
     'the',
     'same',
     'question',
     'just',
     'not',
     'sure',
     'i\'m',
     'ready',
     'to',
     'have',
     'that',
     'conversation' ],
  words: [ 'want' ],
  positive: [ 'want' ],
  negative: [] }

A thing of beauty by:
 @youtube
{ score: 3,
  comparative: 0.25,
  tokens: 
   [ 'a',
     'thing',
     'of',
     'beauty',
     'by',
     'youtube', ],
  words: [ 'beauty' ],
  positive: [ 'beauty' ],
  negative: [] }

do you still do this??
{ score: 0,
  comparative: 0,
  tokens: 
  [
     'do',
     'you',
     'still',
     'do',
     'this' ],
  words: [],
  positive: [],
  negative: [] }
```

As you can see each tweet has their individual sentiment score of respectively `1,1,3,0` So why is my if/else statement disregarding those numbers?

What can I change in my code so that my if/else statement correctly implements and considers the sentiment score of the tweets? My goal is to output the appropriate color for each tweet.

Comment: So you're comparing an object with a number?

Comment: So you want the score?? `twitterSentiment  = results.score;`??

Comment: As zerkms says, `twitterSentiment` is an _object_ ... that object does not equal zero. That object is not less-than zero, therefore the final else is executed. It doesn't even make sense to use numerical comparisons on an object vs. an integer.  Maybe you want to compare `twitterSentiment.score == 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting twitterSentiment to the result object and comparing the whole object instead of just the score. Change your code to:

```
if (twitterSentiment.score == 0) {
    geoColor = '#B5B5B5';
} 

else if (twitterSentiment.score < 0) {
    geoColor = '#FC0828';
} 
else {
   geoColor = '#00DE1E';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your var `results` is an object, that contains many other attributes. In javascript the "if" clause will always return "true" for non-null object instance. When comparing an object to a number - any instance of a non-primitive object will return `1`.

As you said, you want to compare the value of your `score` attribute, so what you need to do is reference your `results.score` in your if clause.

Changing to

```
 twitterSentiment = results.score;
```

Should fix your issue.

Comment: When answering it is recommended you add some guidance rather than just posting the solution.